# Is this the right way to split a big dataframe into smaller ones with certain count of rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my code below. For example, each smaller df contains 3000 rows.

```
def partition_df(df):
    partitioned_df = []
    smaller_df = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        smaller_df.append(row)
        if (index % 3000) == 0 and index != 0:
            partitioned_df.append(pd.DataFrame(smaller_df))
            smaller_df.clear()

    if smaller_df:
        partitioned_df.append(pd.DataFrame(smaller_df))
    return partitioned_df
```

Is there any issue with this split?

Comment: Are you trying to split it to smaller chunks to save?

Comment: There is a memory issue in later operation. So I read the whole file into memory and partition into smaller dfs, and due to the smaller size, the memory issue is gone in later stage. In the end, those smaller dfs will be saved individually. So one big input file to produce multiple smaller files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to split them and save them then you can make use of the `chunksize` argument when loading in the dataframe.

```
chunk_size=3000

for idx, chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv('file.csv',chunksize=chunk_size)):
    chunk.to_csv(f'chunk_{idx}.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: So each chunk is already a dataframe which have the same column names?

Comment: Yes you don't need to load the whole thing in memory with this.

Comment: I like this better due to memory consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a function `np.split` which already does this:

```
partitioned_df = np.split(df, [3000])
```

And convert to list:

```
partitioned_df = np.split(df, [3000]).tolist()
```

Comment: So np.array_split can also take a dataframe object as input as you wrote?

Comment: @marlon yes, exactly! You should try it.

Comment: I tested and it seems that the '3000' is 3000 partitions, not 3000 rows in each partition.

Comment: @marlon Sorry it's my bad, edited my answer.

Comment: This is very concise.

Comment: @marlon If you're not reading csvs this is the only way to go. And also it's much faster since it's in Numpy.

Comment: Yes. It works great. In my case, it's a bit better to read in chunks, since the file is huge.

Comment: @marlon I am not sure which is more efficient, I guess you should time both of the answers and check the times.

Comment: I mean memory wise, reading in chunks is better than the whole. But lots of times reading the whole thing is better for programing, for example to compute word freq.

Comment: @marlon Ah, I got you.

Comment: Just tested. This is to split the df into two chunks, not n chunks with size=3000.